# Need to remove a part from Power Apps Output

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, microsoft-graph

I have made a power app which returns a list of Email Address of SharePoint owners.

I need to remove the part of email and curly bracket from the output (Please refer image). How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Which action have you used to return the results from flow to app? What is the structure of returned results, array of objects?

Comment: I used Graph API to get the O365 owner details (Mistakenly typed sharepoint owners, but its O365 group owners). Then used select operation to get only email field from the output>> used join operation and joined the output of emails with ";". Finally used respond to powerapps and set variable to powerapps to get the result.(Used split operation in powerapps to get the result in gallery.

Comment: Check my answer given below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make changes to your Power automate flow like:

[image]

Expression used in Respond to PowerApp for flow action:

```
join(body('Select'),';')
```

Then in Power Apps:

1. Call your flow and collect email addresses using formula:

```
Set(varEmailAddresses, FlowName.Run().emailaddresses)
```

2. Add Gallery control in your app and set its `Items` property to:

```
Split(varEmailAddresses, ";")
```

3. Add Label control inside gallery control and set its `Text` property to:

```
ThisItem.Value
```

**Output**:

[image]